# What cause amplitude changed after `multiply`?

Tags: signal-analysis, gnuradio

In Gnuradio,multiply 2 signals as below,max amplitude should be `1*2=2`.

[image]
Output shows the max amplitude beyond 2,around 2.4. What's the reason?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

> multiply 2 signals as below,max amplitude should be 1*2=2.

No, these are complex signals which are *not* harmonic oscillations; the magnitude of the sawtooth is not a constant 1; it exceeds that value.

This is really an exercise in sitting down and doing the complex math:

1. Write down the formula for your specific parametrization of the complex sawtooth **for one period** (GNU Radio makes that easy: Just connect your *Signal Source* producing the sawtooth directly to a *Qt GUI time sink* and observe; then connect it to a *Complex to Magnitude* block and that to a Qt GUI time sink, and ponder the magnitude of the sawtooth).
   Hint: The real part leads the imaginary by a quarter period.
2. Write down the formula for your specific parametrization of the complex cosine, first in complex exponential notation ($e^{j\ldots}$), then as $\Re + j\Im$.
3. Multiply both
4. Take the imaginary part of the product
5. Find the maximum

You'll relatively early see (I think I saw it doing 3., but I also knew what I was looking for) why your assumption that this $\le 2$ is wrong.